# How I can install build-essential in a PC without Internet Connection?

Tags: installation, git-buildpackage

I need to download that package from another PC with Internet and after install it on the Linux PC.

There's any way? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Answer (score 2):

On the Internet-less computer:

- Open the Unity Dash, type "Terminal" and press enter
- In the new window enter `PACKAGENAME=<The name of the Package to install>` and press enter
- The enter this: 
  `apt-get -qqs install $PACKAGENAME | grep Inst | awk '{print $2}' | xargs apt-cache show | grep 'Filename: ' | awk '{print $2}' | while read filepath; do echo "wget \"http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/${filepath}\""; done >downloader.sh`
- A ready-to-use downloader for the package has now been created in you home folder
- Open your home directory in the file browser and move the file `downloader.sh` to the top-level directory of your flash drive
- Eject your flash drive

On the computer with Internet:

- Open the flash drive in a terminal:

  - Insert your flash drive
  - Open your flash drive in the file browser
  - Type `<Ctrl>L` and then `<Ctrl>C` (This will copy the location of your flash drive)
  - Open the Unity Dash, type "Terminal" and press enter
  - In the Terminal type this: `cd <Ctrl><Shift>V<Enter>` (This will move you to the directory of the flash drive)
- Type `sh downloader.sh` and press enter
- Wait for the download to complete
- Eject your flash drive

Back to the Internet-less computer:

- Open the flash drive in a terminal:

  - Insert your flash drive
  - Open your flash drive in the file browser
  - Type `<Ctrl>L` and then `<Ctrl>C` (This will copy the location of your flash drive)
  - Open the Unity Dash, type "Terminal" and press enter
  - In the Terminal type this: `cd <Ctrl><Shift>V<Enter>` (This will move you to the directory of the flash drive)
- Type `sudo dpkg --install *.deb` and press enter
- Wait for the package to install

**Note**: This will only work with packages for the Ubuntu archive!

Comment: Without the Internet connection available at the moment of executing `apt-get install $PACKAGENAME`, "Unable to locate package" error will be returned.

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you!